# Loading HTML elements before PHP parses XML file on same page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a website which recommends videos to people. The recommendation system exists on a server which I poll and receive an xml file in return.

The problem is this recommendation system is still under development and it can take 5+ seconds to receive a response. So I need to develop a loading .gif on the page that will act as a placeholder until the xml file is generated.

The problem is I parse the xml file using PHP so when I try to load the page, it just stays white until the xml is parsed. How do I make it load all the html elements of the page first, and then the recommendations only when they're fully loaded?

Comment: try add the php code at the bottom of the page / add your source code here

Comment: Split your web-page content into 2 parts: first - the page core with _loading_ placeholder - serve it from your PHP on first request from a client. In this main part place AJAX code requesting results of XML processing from external service. This shouls be second part of your page generated in PHP separately from main page. It will replace placeholder with actual data as soon as it become available.

Comment: Do AJAX instead: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%5Bjquery%5D+ajax+load+html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the recomendations via AJAX, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'YOUR_PHP_PARSER_FILE',
    success: function(data) {
      $('#recomendations-wrapper').html(data);
    }
  });  
});
```

If you prefer you can return the information in your PHP file in JSON or XML format.